# Insert into select and update in single query

Tags: sql, mysql

```
I have 4 tables: tempTBL, linksTBL and categoryTBL, extra
```

on my tempTBL I have: ID, name, url, cat, isinserted columns
on my linksTBL I have: ID, name, alias columns
on my categoryTBL I have: cl_id, link_id,cat_id
on my extraTBL I have: id, link_id, value

How do I do a single query to select from tempTBL all items where isinsrted = 0 then insert them to linksTBL and for each record inserted, pickup ID (which is primary) and then insert that ID to categoryTBL with cat_id = 88. after that insert extraTBL ID for link_id and url for value.

I know this is so confusing, put I'll post this anyhow...

This is what I have so far:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO linksTBL (link_id,link_name,alias)
VALUES(NULL,'tex2','hello');         # generate ID by inserting NULL
```

INSERT INTO categoryTBL (link_id,cat_id)
    VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'88');  # use ID in second table

I would like to add here somewhere that it only selects items where isinserted = 0 and iserts those records, and onse inserted, will change isinserted to 1, so when next time it runs, it will not add them again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not possible to do in a single query. you will have to insert the rows, then run a separate update statement.

Comment: @KevinPeno - this needs data from other table what if i have fresh data, i basically want a row to be updated if its already der based on key otherwise insert it

Answer (score 1):

As longneck said, you cannot do multiple things in one query, but you can in a stored procedure.

Comment: This is incorrect. Please see mysql documentation for INSERT ... SELECT here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

Comment: This is not incorrect. You can insert from a select (1 thing), but you can't do 2 inserts (2 things).

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

```
INSERT INTO linksTBL (link_id,link_name,alias)
    SELECT field1, field2, field3
        FROM othertable
    WHERE inserted=0;
```