# Is it possible to use more than one related queries together in MySQL or PostreSQL?

Tags: mysql

I want to use different queries such as update, select and etc. Is it possible to combine them in one query? And how?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596573/insert-into-select-and-update-in-single-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get the "result" of an UPDATE, DELETE or INSERT query in PostgreSQL, you can use the `returning` clause:

```
DELETE FROM my_table
WHERE some_id = ...
RETURNING *;
```

would return all rows that were delete by that statement. Likewise with UPDATE:

```
UPDATE my_table 
   SET column_1 = some_value,  
       column_2 = some_other_value
WHERE some_id = ...
RETURNING *;
```

would return all updated rows with the new values.

I don't think something like this is possible in MySQL though.

Comment: as I understand my single query will be like that:
**$query="DELETE FROM my_table
WHERE some_id = ...
RETURNING *;
UPDATE my_table 
   SET column_1 = some_value,  
       column_2 = some_other_value
WHERE some_id = ...
RETURNING *;
"**

Comment: I don't think you can mix a DELETE And UPDATE statement. You need to run each one by itself. But that depends on your programming language. Some interfaces allow that some not (with JDBC it is not possible)

Answer (score 0):

You can use stored procedures for wrap your functionality, check these documentation:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-stored-procedures/

http://www.eioba.com/a/1ign/a-basic-introduction-to-postgres-stored-procedures